# Javascript Dynamic OnChange Event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add an on change event to an HTML select object.  I can't seem to get it to work.  I need the function to call dropDownChange and pass two parameters, this and nextDepth.

```
   var nextDepth = (int)......
   var selectBox = ......
   selectBox.onchange += function(nextDepth){dropDownChange(this, nextDepth);};
```

Not really sure how to tackle this... I figured this could would work.  Any help you be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your html and real JavaScript? The ellipses don't help me understand what you're trying to do, or worth with... =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeonchange(){
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var nextDepth = getIntFromSomeWhere();

    selectBox.onchange = function() {
        var targ;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.target) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        dropDownChange(targ, nextDepth);
    };
}
```

You can get more info about events from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html every time "changeonchange" is called a new scope is created to hold the local variables and that scope is carried along the new onchange handler.

Comment: Prusse,  The variable nextDepth is an integer declared locally in the function that will be changing the select box's on change event.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are looking for a way to pass in `this` in relation to the current executing object or namespace. To express this, the code example below uses an anonymous function, where `this` is stored to the variable `me`. Then when the `select`'s change event triggers, your custom function is called, passing in the two specified variables.

```
(function() {
    var me = this;
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var nextDepth = 2;

    selectBox.onchange = function() {
        dropDownChange(me, nextDepth);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Greg thanks for the response, I was actually looking to pass this as a pointer to the select box itself.

Comment: @Dave: Passing a function pointer to a DOM object sounds ... well ... it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I mean this as in an instace of the select box.  When it calls dropDownChange it will pass both a pointer to itself and the integer value of nextDepth

Comment: The `this` keyword will point to the selectBox DOMElement *inside* the onchange function.

Comment: It should have been just `dropDownChange.call(this, nextDepth);`. There's no need pass context as an argument.